# How to stop simultaneous login with same user on different pcs

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i came to know from one of stack overflow question that how we can prevent users to stop simultaneous login with same user on different pc.

[How to prevent simultaneous login with same user on different pcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042892/how-to-prevent-simultaneous-login-with-same-user-on-different-pcs?lq=1)

the guy who wrote the question he said that he store session id in db and in every time any user login then read db to check the same session id exist in db or not. if exist then deny to login. i like to know that if i open a same site from different pc then session id would be different. how this kind of check can be successful by session id comparison. if i am wrong then please rectify me. looking for discussion to achieve this job perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer these site it has some useful information regarding your solution

[How to prevent simultaneous login with same user on different pcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042892/how-to-prevent-simultaneous-login-with-same-user-on-different-pcs)

https://serverfault.com/questions/298418/roaming-profiles-simultaneous-logins-of-same-user

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/156590-prevent-same-user-login-to-multiple-computers-simultaneously

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9d6d0da3-6bd5-4155-8921-6afd16b36b70/restrict-simultaneous-logons-for-same-user